# How to show foreign key value in datagrid view using Entity Framework C# Winforms?

Tags: database, entity-framework, datagridview, foreign-keys

I want to show the foreign key value in data grid view using Entity Framework in a C# Winforms application.

I have a table `customer` and another `customer_type`. In table `customer`, I have foreign key `customer_type` which references the `customer_type` table. I want to show all the information in `customer` table but foreign key value from `customer_type`. How can I do that? Please help.

Here is my code I am using:

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    using (var db = new Vehicle_Management_SystemContext())
    {
        var customer = from Customer in db.Customers.Include("Customer_Type")
                       select Customer;

        return customer.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you expose the foreign key property in your Customer class? If you don't, there's no way other than querying the database for it, since it doesn't even get filled into the object (or into the DbSet, for that matter)

Comment: yes i have added foriegn key in customer class

Comment: It's a **customer** - not a "costumer" .....

Comment: where have i written ''costumer'' ??

Comment: Please provide code for `Customer` and `Customer_Type` classes. If you use code first approach and there exist some custom configuration - post these too.

Comment: i am using database first approach
``

Comment: problem solved thanx all i am not declaring the field name in datgridview  :D